# JavaScript execute page resize and reload event simultaneously

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onload, event-listener

I am trying to execute a window resize and page reload event simultaneously. When the screen size is less than 768 px, I am adding an attribute to an element. I also need that attribute added when the page is reload and a specific size as well, not just when its resized. The code I have below works, except when my screen size hs < 769 px, it takes a few seconds for the attribute to be added which affects how it looks. Any tips on how I can fix this?

```
window.onload = function(event) {

var element = document.querySelector('.filter-select');

if (window.innerWidth < 768)  {
  element.classList.add('testing');
  element.removeAttribute("size", "4")
  element.removeAttribute("multiple", "yes")    
} else {
       element.classList.remove('testing');
    }    
}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var element = document.querySelector('.filter-select');

  function resize() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
      element.classList.add('testing');
      element.removeAttribute("size", "4")
      element.removeAttribute("multiple", "yes")
    } else {
      element.classList.remove('testing');
    }
  }
  window.onresize = resize;
});
```

Comment: It might be not useful in your case, but when working with non dynamic websites ( non SPA ) it's almost always easier to render all the elements on backend and then hide the one which you don't need at certain breakpoint with css. If you have common breakpoints you use you just add a helper classes and can reuse it later. Most of css frameworks will have something like that, for example  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/. As long as your css is in header link and not loaded asynchronously you will not have a flicker happening.

Answer (score 1):

My only guess is that you doubled up the same process under different events and these events happen at different times thus the NOTICABLE lag.. if this doesn't solve.. this is an amazing question I already upvoted..

```
function resize() {
  var element = document.querySelector('.filter-select')
  if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
    element.classList.add('testing')
    element.removeAttribute("size", "4")
    element.removeAttribute("multiple", "yes")
  }
  else {
    element.classList.remove('testing');
  }
}
window.onload=resize
```

Comment: yes thank you, unfortunately this didn't solve the issue so still searching for a solution!

Comment: @KatherineMichelle i bookmarked it.. if by like 2 days there still isn't a solve this question might be my first bounty placement

Comment: @KatherineMichelle it seems this problem remains unsolved huh